# Extaer los ultimos caracteres de un string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Necesito ayuda para extraer los últimos 8 caracteres de una ruta ya que es el nombre de una carpeta y a la vez es una fecha de consulta.

```
string ruta = "C:\\Users\\luis\\Desktop\\DATA\\_ENV\\2020\\20200101";
```

No debo ocupar subtring ya que dicha ruta cambia en el servidor.
Saludos.

Comment: podes usar substrings sin problemas... porque no??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el **método GetFileName**:

```
var último = Path.GetFileName(ruta);
```

Este método devuelve la cadena que viene después del último **\** en la ruta por lo q no importa si son **8** o cualquier cantidad de caracteres.

Para usar este método debes poner en los **using**:

```
using System.IO;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió a la perfección.